# first-order linear differential equation's solving method (integrating both sides of the equation part)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

so we all know how to solve first-order linear differential equation, where after we found the integrating factor $e^{\int P(x)dx}$ then the equation goes $\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{\int P(x)dx})=e^{\int P(x)dx}Q(x)$. The next step is to integrating both side, so we have:

$ye^{\int P(x)dx}=\int e^{\int P(x)dx}Q(x)dx$

this part is when im starting to have question, why we suddenly could integrate both side specially the right side  of the equation? why we suddenly have $dx$ on the right side? i don't think the $dx$ is the conscequence of the integral so am i missing something here?

i think it has something to do with anti-derivative concept but i couldn't get my logic straight, yet. so a little hint or answer would help, thanks.

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem of infinitesimal calculus, if $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$, then $F(x)=\int f(x)\,ds+C$, meaning $F$ is among the primitives/anti-derivatives of $f$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann im sorry but what is $\int{f(x)ds+C}$?

Comment: The undetermined (Riemann) integral. It should of course have been $\int f(x)\,dx$ or $F(0)+\int_0^x f(s)\,ds$.